# composite primary key with foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have a database 'STUDENT'. There are 4 table 'INFO','STREAM','GRADE' & 'MARKS'.

- INFO has 3 columns ID, NAME, STR_NO.
- STREAM has 2 columns STR_NO, STR_NAME.
- GRADE has 2 columns PERCENT, GRADE.
- MARKS has 3 columns ID, STR_NO, TOTAL_MARK, FULL_MARK

I have declared a composite primary key on info table i.e

```
PRIMARY KEY(ID, STR_NO)
```

But when I declare a foreign key on STREAM i.e

```
FOREIGN KEY(STR_NO) REFERENCES INFO(ID,STR_NO)
```

It gives error

Why and how to solve this

Comment: A foreign key must reference **all** columns of the primary key.

Comment: Which means you have to have the same two columns on the Stream table to use as foreign key (ID and STR_NO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what your tables are representing, it looks like you have the foreign key relationship backwards. It looks like `STR_NO` should be the primary key on `STREAM`, and that there should be a foreign key constraint on `INFO` requiring that `INFO.STR_NO` have a matching value in `STREAM.STR_NO` - or, in code

```
ALTER TABLE INFO
  ADD CONSTRAINT INFO_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (STR_NO) REFERENCES STREAM(STR_NO);
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
ALTER TABLE STREAM ADD(ID NUMBER)

ALTER TABLE INFO
  ADD CONSTRAINT INFO_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (ID, STR_NO) REFERENCES STREAM(ID, STR_NO);
```

Since Table Info has a composite primary key `ID, STR_NO`, then any reference to it must also include both columns.

For more detail, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996774/foreign-key-relationship-with-composite-primary-keys-in-sql-server-2005).