# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table error

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a problem with combining foreign keys to different tables. For example I made a table Customers and a Table invoices. I want a foreign key from Customers to invoices so I can get the name and everything of the Customer:

Create table code of `Customers`:

```
Create Table Customers
(
    customerID int IDENTITY(100,1) NOT NULL, 
    customer_email varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    insertion varchar(10)   NULL,
    phonenumber int NULL,
    streetname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    number  int NOT NULL,
    zipcode varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    city    varchar(255) NOT NULL,

    Constraint pk_Customers 
       PRIMARY KEY (customerID, customer_email, username)
)
```

Create table code of `Invoices`:

```
Create Table Invoices 
(
    invoiceID int IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    customer_email varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    customerID int NOT NULL,
    creationdate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    totalAmount decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,

    Constraint pk_Invoices 
        PRIMARY KEY (invoiceID, customer_email,creationdate)
)
```

The foreign key code that I want to use:

```
ALTER Table Invoices
ADD Constraint fk_Customers_Invoices 
FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customers (customerID)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE 
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

It throws the following error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Customers' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_Customers_Invoices'.

How can I add my foreign key?

Comment: A bit odd structure. If `CustomerID` is an `identity` column then why are there any other columns in `PRIMARY KEY`? Both of your PKs must by on identity col. I can't even imagine what would be the purpose of unique constraint on **customer_email+creationdate**... You are getting an error because your PK consists of three columns but you are attempting to reference it with only one column. One column is not enough to locate record which is identified by three columns. Fix your PKs as I mentioned above and FK will work fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996774/foreign-key-relationship-with-composite-primary-keys-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Customers` table defines this primary key:

```
Constraint pk_Customers 
   PRIMARY KEY (customerID, customer_email, username)
```

any table that wants to reference `Customers` **must provide all three columns** of that primary key. That's the way FK constraints work.

So from your `Invoices` tables, you **must provide all 3 columns** that make up the primary key of `Customers` - not just one. You can **never** refernce only part of a primary key - it's the **whole key** or nothing....

```
ALTER Table Invoices
ADD Constraint fk_Customers_Invoices 
FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customers (customerID)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE 
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

You can **either**:

- change the PK for `Customers` to be just `CustomerID` which would make a whole lot more sense since it's an **identity** column
- or you could add the other two columns in the `Customers` PK to yoru table `Invoices`

Comment: But with this i can still use the function     UNIQUE  right?

Comment: @CarstenFlokstra: not sure what you refer to - `UNIQUE` on / for what ?!?!?

Comment: That there are unique values in the database with customer_email and username.

Comment: It is strange to have copies of usernames en customer_email adresses.

Comment: @CarstenFlokstra: well in that case, make the `CustomerID` **alone** the PK! That makes the most sense. And then you don't have "copies" of "user names" and "customer_email" addresses in other tables either.... to ensure uniqueness for `(username, customer_email)`, you can always put an **UNIQUE CONSTRAINT** on those two columns - they don't need to be part of the PK !

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because your primary key is a composite key:

```
customerID, customer_email, username
```

This suggests that it is only the combination of these three fields that will uniquely identify a customer, and the foreign key would need to reference all three fields.

If customerID is unique, then it should be the primary key for the table and your foreign keys would be able to use it as a reference.

For what purpose are the other fields included in the primary key?