# Why is my create table failing? - does not match primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what I am trying to create:

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLEREPORT 
(
    DeptID char(2)    not null,
    Vin#   char(3)    not null,         
    Miles  varchar(6) not null,
    Bill#  char(3)    not null,
    EID    char(3)    not null,

    PRIMARY KEY (DeptID, Vin#),
    FOREIGN KEY (bill#) REFERENCES billing,
    FOREIGN KEY (EID) REFERENCES Employee
);
```

The issue is with my reference to billing. The error says:

> The number of columns in the referencing column list for foreign key 'FK__VEHICLERE__Bill#__5AEE82B9' does not match those of the primary key in the referenced table 'Billing'.

but my billing table entered fine:

```
CREATE TABLE BILLING 
(
    VIN#  char(3),      
    BILL# char(3),      

    PRIMARY KEY (VIN#, Bill#),
    FOREIGN KEY (VIN#) REFERENCES vehicle
);
```

What am i missing with this?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: BILLING has a two column primary key. You're attempting to create a foreign key reference to it using a single column. The error message pretty well already told you that. How to correct it depends on what the data structure is meant to actually be - should BILLING actually have a single column PK, or should the FK be using VIN# as well as bill#?

Comment: That's one of the clearest error messages I've seen.

Comment: Despite it being pretty clear, I cant figure out how to fix it. BILLING should have both VIN# and Bill# as the PK. Even when adding VIN# to the FK in the code, the reference billing still errors :(

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (VIN#,Bill#) REFERENCES billing`

Comment: There is a post on this topic. Please find the link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996774/foreign-key-relationship-with-composite-primary-keys-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: @dnoeth That did allow the table to correctly create, but I am now getting a similar insert error:



 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__VEHICLEREPORT__6477ECF3". The conflict occurred in database "SP18_CIS365_22830_team5", table "dbo.BILLING".

Comment: Yep, what do you expect? You're trying to insert invalid data and the Foreign Key constraint prevens that.

Comment: @dnoeth I'm honestly not sure. I've inserted ~6 tables to my DBMS tonight and this is the first wall I'm hitting and not sure how to fix.

Comment: Since the types of bill# and vin# are identical, make sure that you're specifying them in the *same order* everywhere that you're defining them as keys. If you're not paying attention, you could easily now have set it up so that VEHICLEREPORT's vin# must match billings bill# and vice versa.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't know that the keys also have to be in the same order I thought just declaring them as PK/FK was enough. . In BILLING, the VIN# is before Bill#. I'm not sure how to change that unless I delete the entire table and just switch it around in a new create table statement.

Comment: Since there's no requirement that the *names* match between the foreign key columns and the primary key columns, the only way to define what you want to match up is the column order.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Man this table is a nightmare. I deleted the BILLING table, changed order to put BILL# at top, created the table again. I created this one, VehicleReport ok, but now I am getting truncation errors, all the sizes are the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of the foreign key as establishing a parent-child relationship between two tables, then the parent side column(s) need to be unique.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key):

> In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that uniquely identifies a row of another table or the same table. ... In simpler words, the foreign key is defined in a second table, but it refers to the primary key or a unique key in the first table.

In your example, there is no guarantee that VIN# is unique in VEHICLEREPORT. Below are your options

1. VIN# is guaranteed to be unique in VEHICLEREPORT. In this case add a UNIQUE constraint on VIN# on the VEHICLEREPORT table. The error will go away.
2. VIN# is not unique in VEHICLEREPORT (doesn't seem likely). If this is the case, then likely there is a flaw in the design of your BILLING table as it could likely point to more than one row in VEHICLEREPORT. You should consider adding DeptID column to BILLING and creating a composite foreign key.

Also if VIN# is unique (case 1 above), you should think of why DeptID is present in the PK. Maybe the right fix at the end is to drop DeptID from the primary key.