# SQL Server why am I getting error for creating foreign key constraint for no matching key in referenced table?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I get this error from SQL Server:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 64
> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Orders' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_Cart_Orders'.

However, the `OrderID` column is in the `Orders` table, so I cannot understand why the error says there is no matching keys in the `Orders` table. I am obviously doing something wrong but do not know what it is.

My code is fairly short and is:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestMattressSite
GO

USE TestMattressSite
GO

CREATE TABLE Mattresses 
(
    MattressID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Customers 
(
    CustomerID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Orders 
(
    OrderID BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE Cart 
(
    OrderID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    MattressID INT NOT NULL,
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE Mattresses 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Mattresses PRIMARY KEY (MattressID)
GO

ALTER TABLE Customers 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Customers PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
GO

ALTER TABLE Orders 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Orders PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, CustomerID)
GO

ALTER TABLE Cart 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Cart PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, MattressID)
GO

ALTER TABLE Orders 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Customers 
        FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers (CustomerID)
GO

ALTER TABLE Cart 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Cart_Mattresses 
            FOREIGN KEY (MattressID) REFERENCES Mattresses (MattressID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_Cart_Orders 
            FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES Orders (OrderID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_Cart_Customers 
            FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers (CustomerID)
GO
```

Can someone please take a look and point out my error?

Comment: What is the PK of Orders? It is <OrderID, CustomerID> (which is a problem). Your FK must include both columns.

Comment: So you are saying since my key that I am referencing is a composite key, then I must use the whole composite (both fields) even if I want only to use one of the fields as a foreign key, correct?

Comment: You **CANNOT** reference on part of a primary key - if your primary key (in  `Orders`) contains **two columns** - then all your foreign keys referencing that PK **must also** contain those two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `Orders` table have primary key on two columns `OrderID` and `CustomerID`, its a composite primary key so when you want to reference this key as foreign key any table, you need to define all the column of composite primary key, like below.

```
ALTER TABLE Cart ADD
   CONSTRAINT FK_Cart_Mattresses FOREIGN KEY (MattressID)  REFERENCES Mattresses (MattressID),
   CONSTRAINT FK_Cart_Orders FOREIGN KEY (OrderID, CustomerID) REFERENCES Orders (OrderID, CustomerID),
   CONSTRAINT FK_Cart_Customers FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers (CustomerID)
GO
```

**Or,**

If you want your foreign key to have only one column `OrderID`, change your primary key like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders ADD
   CONSTRAINT PK_Orders PRIMARY KEY (
      OrderID
   )
GO
```

With this, you current query will work as it is.

There already a question on this, refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996774/foreign-key-relationship-with-composite-primary-keys-in-sql-server-2005).

Comment: I took a long look at what I was doing and realized that I should have only OrderID as the primary key in my orders table.  Thanks for the help and explanations.